# What ISO date format is this?

Tags: php, date, isodate

I could not locate this format, can you tell me please what ISO format is this?

```
2016-09-30T09:18:29.044Z
```

I need to recreate this in PHP.

It is similar to ISO-8601 (`date('c')`) but the ending is different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It still is ISO 8601, but there are different versions for this available.
Check the [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime) about this. There are 6 different versions:

```
Year:
  YYYY (eg 1997)
Year and month:
  YYYY-MM (eg 1997-07)
Complete date:
  YYYY-MM-DD (eg 1997-07-16)
Complete date plus hours and minutes:
  YYYY-MM-DDThh:mmTZD (eg 1997-07-16T19:20+01:00)
Complete date plus hours, minutes and seconds:
  YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssTZD (eg 1997-07-16T19:20:30+01:00)
Complete date plus hours, minutes, seconds and a decimal fraction of a second
  YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sTZD (eg 1997-07-16T19:20:30.45+01:00)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is still a valid ISO date. The 'Z' at the end of `2016-09-30T09:18:29.044Z` simply means that it's a UTC date.

Comment: That is true, but who does it have seconds as `.004` and not `:004` ?

Comment: It doesn't `2016-09-30T09:18:29.044Z` has a :29 seconds. The .044 in this case is the fraction of a second, or microsecond if you will for this stamp.